# C# and SQLite: "no such table error" when using relative path?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am having issues connecting to my sqlite database. The file is located in the application's folder. Here is the connection string

```
string path = "Data Source=MY.db";
```

I can get it to work if I use the absolute path, but it gives me a "table not found" error if I try to use a relative path. Any ideas?

Comment: change ===> configuration manager > Active Solotion platform >"Any cpu"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are opening up a different -- perhaps a *new* -- database that does not have said table. (Yes, SQLite will happily create a new database with the default connection settings.)

Make sure the *correct* database is opened. Remember, *relative* path is relative to the [Current Working Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is likely not that which is expected.

(The working directory is influenced from where, and how, the process is loaded. The working directory for a "Debug" session can be set under Project Settings / Debug / Start Options, for instance.)

Happy coding.

See also:

- [Make SQLite connection fail if database is missing? (deleted/moved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807208/try-catch-sqlite-net-open-connection)
- [Defining a working directory for executing a program (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719293/defining-a-working-directory-for-executing-a-program-c) (Shows how to set the current working directory to the directory containing the executing assembly.)
- [How do I get/set a winforms application's working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590097/how-do-i-get-set-a-winforms-applications-working-directory)
- [Getting path relative to the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory)

Comment: This was indeed the problem. When backing up and restoring the sqlite files in my app, "i" always used the same working directory. But when moving/copying the file to a new working directory, Sqlite would create an empty db with that file name, frustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when you haven't saved the database and its table while using GUI Manager for SQLite .
Two solution;
1) Save your database and its table with CTR+S in GUI Manager
2) Or Simply Just close your GUI manager of SQlite and save all .

Important !  I am using GUI manger for SQLITE (DB Browser for SQLITE) and its all about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for both my windows application (C#) and web application (ASP.net). I usually use SQLite because I found it more easier, especially when I worked with connection strings. But the main obstacle for me was to put a relative path in my code, so I can publish it without worrying about being unable to find the database. I've tried many things(using "|Data Directory|", "~/", "./", ...), and none of them works until I found these solutions. It seems the code is working for me, but wonder if I'm using them right?!

Web Application:

```
    SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("~/") + "mydb.db; Version = 3; New = false;);
```

Windows App:

```
    SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source =" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "mydb.db; Version = 3; New = false; Read Only = true");
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your .database file into \bin\Debug in project folder, because in your case compiler creates DB file with same name but its totally empty 0bytes