# How do I get sqlite to error instead of creating a missing database file in golang?

Tags: go, sqlite

I'm opening a connection to a sqlite database of the user's choosing in my golang program. If they supply a path to a non-existent file then I want to throw an error instead of creating the file.

I'm using the [mattn/gp-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) driver. The documentation doesn't mention this capability as far as I can see.

- The [sqlite C documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) mentions the querystring format but not the existence of the target file.
- The [C# connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) have a `FailIfMissing` option but are in a different format.

This is the same as [Make SQLite connection fail if database is missing? (deleted/moved)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/807208/10245) but for golang instead of C#. The golang driver seems to use a different format for describing connections to the C# driver so I don't know if the answers there translate to golang or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the go-sqlite3 library. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/1828334c4a7937cf4d957e36e995b9d6ba4fc535/sqlite3.go#L689-L693), you can see `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` is always passed to the open function:

```
rv := C._sqlite3_open_v2(name, &db,
    C.SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX|
        C.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|
        C.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
    nil)
```

I would suggest you [open a ticket](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/new) on the package to add such functionality.

In the mean time, you could add the following code before your DB is created (keep in mind that a race condition exists, which is why you should still request this feature in the library itself):

```
_, err := os.Stat("db.sqlite3")
if os.IsNotExist(err) {
    panic("database doesn't exist")
}
// TODO: create db
```